# saving a VB timespan value in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, timespan

What data type can I store a VB timespan that is greater than 24 hours?
The following will not save as a SQL timespan value.

```
Dim span As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(1, 2, 0, 30, 0)
```

Output

1.02:00:30

I would like to be able to perform calculations on this later.

SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '1.02:00:30' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

This Fiddler sample shows the results I am after, and I would like to store the results in a SQL database.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7b0d/53

Comment: SQL Server has no interval data type, so it isn't clear what you're trying to do here. A common approach on the database side is to [store intervals as integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911900/storing-durations-timespans-in-sql-server), i.e. number of ticks, seconds or minutes or whatever granularity that you need. Then you can format it however you like in your applications. Alternatively you could store the start and end times of the interval.

Comment: Updated Post with sample.

Comment: As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) says, the `time` data type stores a time of day, not a period of time (interval). Therefore the best option is probably to store the number of seconds, which makes calculations easy. But converting the number of seconds to a specific string format for output (which is what your SQL Fiddle does) is something that should usually be done in the application, not in the database.

Comment: I agree with you, @Pondlife, and you should make that your answer.

Comment: Well it is being done in the code, and the issue as stated in the opening sentence is "What data type can I store the value as and still calculate with it?" I do understand the limits of the time type, the error clearly spells it out. Was hoping for some ideas or suggestions to meet the goal.

Comment: If using an integer isn't suitable, then I suggest you explain why and give some more background about your calculations. Someone else may have an alternative suggestion in that case.

Comment: The simplest answer is readability. The results get displayed to user and it would be nice if there was a data type to support this time interval. I am investigating overrides now, but all of the calculations required for the number of records at presentation time may not be feasible for my project.

Comment: It still isn't clear what your calculations are or where you do them: in the database or in the application? I would store the timespan in seconds (for example) in the database in an `integer` column, and use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` and `TimeSpan.FromSeconds()` when you store and retrieve it from the DB. That way if your calculations are in the database you can work with seconds; if they're in your application then you can work with `TimeSpan` objects natively. Would this work for you?

Comment: Not sure I can make it more clear than the Fiddler example. I want to store TotalTime in a SQL db without making it a string, or doing crazy integer calculations. Looking for the best way to achieve this. Was hoping for a Date, datetime, or some other simple process to store the resutls without bigint calculations.

Comment: @pondlife, sorry this took so long but I used your suggestion and simply built a function to return the presentation values. If you post as an answer I will accept your post. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I initially suggested the SQL Server 2008 "datetimeoffset" datatype but that is wrong.

As previous comments correctly indicated, there is currently no data type in SQL Server that naturally stores and handles timespan values.

The simplest alternative would be to store the offset as a floating point value with the integer portion representing days, and the fractional part representing the portion of the day.  This would allow for simple calculations.  The math could be done as follows:

```
select 
    getdate(),                                          -- Current datetime
    CONVERT(date, getdate()),                           -- Current date
    CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, getdate())) +1,     -- Add one day
    CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, getdate())) +1.75   -- Add a day + 3/4 or 18 hours
    getdate() + .75,                                    -- Current Time + 18 hours.
    getdate() + (3/4)                                   -- Current Time + 18 hours.
```

NOTE: You can only do this kind of datetime math with the [datetime] datatype.  Therefore the need to convert the [date] datatype back to a [datetime].

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question, I was trying to store total time only in the span. Not calendar days.

Comment: I understood your question but my answer was totally wrong.  I had conflated the MSSqlServer [datetimeoffset] datatype with the MySQL [Time] datatype which is not like the MSSQL [Time] datatype.  I will rewrite my answer.